# How to detect "half-downloaded" files in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to handle the download of some files in my app. Basically I download a file when needed and show it to the user.

I also want to seize the downloaded files as cache, so I use a hash over the url and when the map collides with an existing file I consider it a cache hit.

My pseudo code is:

```
String filename = hash(url);
File outputFile = new File(cacheFolder,filename);
if(!outputFile.exists()){
   download(url,outputFile);
}
return outputFile;
```

The code I'm using to download the file from the url is;

```
URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
// this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

// download the file
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

It works nice but I have a problem for detecting the following case:

- The app starts downloading a file, while partially written, the user kills the app, leaving the output file in a inconsistent state.
- The user reopens the app, I detect the file exists but I can't detect the file is corrupt, so I try to open the file, failing.

How can I solve this?

Should I download in a temp file and copy it to the outputFile while completed? Or this could cause a unnecessary overhead.

Is there some way to avoid the file to be created until the download is finished without using the temporally file+copy approach?

Thanks

Comment: I see 2 options, trying to load it anyway, so you will know if its corrupt because it will fail, and the other is checking the file size, but you will need to store apart the original size.

Comment: download to a temp file and then *move* it to the final location. no overhead at all.

Comment: How does you app reference downloaded files? It must have a list of file it thinks it can open, is this just "all files in a folder" or a lookup list (database) of downloaded files? If you have a list, then you could add a flag property to say "DownloadComplete" for example, which is only set at the end of successful download. Or you could use temp file names for download, and then just rename them when the download completes

Comment: *The user reopens the app, I detect the file exists but I can't detect the file is corrupt, so I try to open the file, failing*. If you fill up correctly the `content-length` you could check the different between the stored file size and the field

Comment: Maintain a table with the expected file lengths and compare them to the effective file sizes.

Comment: Use a MD5 verification?
Something to look at : http://www.codejacked.com/using-md5sum-to-validate-the-integrity-of-downloaded-files/

Comment: Or what you can do is, something that I have seen chrome do. It maintains the file under download in a different format. Once the download is complete, it renames(not sure if its rename or its converting) to the actual file name. 

So what you can do is download file as eg: abc.exe.temp and once the download is complete rename it back to abc.exe.. or if download fails then on restart of app.. clear all the abc.exe.temp files